# Infopath Form with Many data connections

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have a custom list which has many data connections

in the Infopath data connections when I add connection I unchecked the automatically load data

now in my dropdowns which are connected to the data connections it does not loads data.
how can I query and set the dropdowns data on change of field not on load of the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that by following the below steps in your info-path form:

1- go to your field that should triggers the data loading and right click 
2- select **Rules**-**Manage Rules** 
[image]

3- At the rules window on the right of the screen , click new - Action to create a new Action rule 
[image]

4- on **Run These Actions** add two actions

1. **Set Field Value**, which you should set the Query value in your Data conection

   [image]
2. Second action is  **Query using Data connection** and select your data connection 
   [image]

Comment: Thanks, I actually put the rule in different control which was not working and  that made my day ha ha.

Comment: @MehdiJalal welcome, glad  i could help